# Is there a limit to the number of FTDI connections on Debian 9?

Tags: usb-device, ttyusb, lsusb, uart

I have a Debian 9 box, and if I plug in 1 of my devices, its UART shows up in both `lsusb` and in the output of `ls /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/`.

When I attach 2, the 2nd one always shows up.

But for some number greater than 2, no new entries appear in `lsusb` or `usb-serial/devices/`.  It also seems to be kind of random: sometimes the 3rd device will show up, sometimes not.

This behavior is the same across 3 different brands of USB hub.  I also tried connecting these devices on MacOS, and got a similar behavior.

Currently my `lsusb` looks like this (other hubs and devices omitted for clarity):

```
... snip
Bus 001 Device 042: ID 0403:6014 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232H Single HS USB-UART/FIFO IC
Bus 001 Device 040: ID 0403:6014 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232H Single HS USB-UART/FIFO IC
Bus 001 Device 036: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 039: ID 10c4:ea71 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 037: ID 0403:6014 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232H Single HS USB-UART/FIFO IC
... snip
```

Is there some system setting preventing the additional devices from showing up?

Comment: "No new entries in `lsusb`" is definitely strange. Power issues (though that's unlikely for a UART)? Did your hubs include a powered one? Proprietary FTDI magic? In theory, you should be able to plug in as many devices as you want.

Comment: I got the same behavior across 2 different brands of powered hub, *and* 2 different brands of unpowered hub.

Comment: Very curious. Anything interesting in `dmesg`?

Comment: had to get permission on the server to use `dmesg` but that was a very helpful suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## yes

This is a limitation of the Intel xHCI chipset used on the motherboard.

Specifically, most of these chips limit the number of "devices" to 32.  But a single physical thing like a camera may appear to the USB controller chip as multiple "devices".  Plus each hub counts as at least 1 "device" so you can easily run into this limit much earlier than you might expect.

In my case, I believe each FTDI chip shows up as 4 devices, plus for some reason the xHCI chip has a max of 16, so I run out after about the 2nd or 3rd physical device is plugged in with a cable.

As visible from `dmesg`:

```
[4173630.423513] usb 1-1.2.3-port3: couldn't allocate usb_device
[4173630.430741] xhci_hcd 0000:00:0f.0: Error while assigning device slot ID
[4173630.437521] xhci_hcd 0000:00:0f.0: Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 16.
```

The solutions I've found so far essentially boil down to:

1. add a dedicated PCI USB controller [more detail here](https://acroname.com/blog/why-cant-i-connect-more-usb-30-devices-my-system)
2. downgrade to `ehci` if possible, to force USB 2.0 and therefore a limit of 128 devices [as explained here](http://marc.merlins.org/perso/linux/post_2018-12-20_Getting-Around-USB3-xhci-32-Device-Limit-_Max-number-of-devices-this-xHCI-host-supports-is-32_.html)

In my case it wasn't possible to downgrade the fancy new server to `ehci`, so we're going to try to use the USB 2.0 ports in the old legacy server as our USB interface.  I found it very frustrating that the supposedly "better" USB 3.0 has this limitation.